# How to only show child directory in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I decided to try WordPress and in order to be able to use the smartness of PhpStorm, it told me to use WordPress root folder. This annoys me cause I see a lot of unused files in the project sidebar (see in image below).

[image: Scope]

I only want to see the folder that I surrounded with the red box.

I have searched for this but couldn't find any good answer. The best thing I found is that it hides all other folders, but still shows the folders `wordpress > wp-content > fictional-uni` and I rather only see the folder `fictional-university`

Comment: You can add the folder to [the favorites](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/managing-your-project-favorites.html).

Comment: Oh thanks this works!

Comment: You can create custom Scope and then switch to using it in Project View panel (instead of "Project" that you have right now). Is this is what you have tried?

Comment: Also -- have a look at this official tutorial -- it may give you other ideas: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/WordPress+Development+using+PhpStorm  -- e.g. if you keep your theme code separately from actual WP code (have not used it for WP coding myself -- I've included whole WP folder and it worked just fine for me)

Comment: @LazyOne ye I saw that tutorial, I followed it but somehow when I add the wordpress include to my php. I t doesn't show up in my external library and I won't get any suggestions trying to autfill code related to wordpress.

Comment: @LazyOne and yes the custom scope is what I tried, only downside to that is that it still showed the folders `wordpress` and `wp-content`. I allways worked with a clean sidenav and it being filled annoys me. Also its going a bit to the right every folder that it digs in. But thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the folder to the favorites. There is a [Favorites Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/favorites-tool-window.html) to see and [manage all your favorites](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/managing-your-project-favorites.html). To add a folder to the favorites you can right click the folder and select `Add to Favorites`. There you can select a favorite list too to organize your favorites.